# Solutions for big data preprecessing for feeding deep neural network models built with TensorFlow 2.0?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, bigdata, data-processing, feature-engineering

Currently I am using Python, Numpy, pandas, scikit-learn to do data preprocessing (**LabelEncoder, MinMaxScaler, fillna, etc.**), and then feeding the processed data to DNN models built with Tensorflow 2.0. This input pipeline meets my needs when data is small enough to fit a PC's RAM.

Now I have some large datasets, more than 10GB, some are larger. I also plan to deploy the models in a production environment, which means there will be new data coming everyday. For DNN model training there is distributed strategy of tensorflow 2.0. But for data preprocessing obviously I cannot use pandas, scikitlearn on the large datasets with one PC. It seems to me I need to use a for-loop where I repeatedly fetch a small part of the data and use it for training?

**I am wondering what do people typically use in either experiment or production environment for big data preprocessing?**
Should I use `Spark(Scala) / PySpark` and [`Tensorflow input pipeline`](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data)?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, with the current way you are doing preprocessing, it'll not scale well.
PySpark is one right way to run your preprocessing layer. Setup a simple standalone spark cluster with few workers and then run your preprocessing (labelEncoder/OneHotEncoder/fillNA/...) This solution should scale well and it abstracts the distributed computation layer.

PS : PySpark might not be the only way forward, but it is one of the good way forward for this use case.